# how to specify the time zone (TZ) in parameterizedCron Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

How to specify the time zone (TZ) in parameterizedCron Jenkins plugin in a Declarative and scripted pipeline?

The below syntax is reported as error during execution of a build

```
properties([
        pipelineTriggers([parameterizedCron('''TZ=Asia/Kolkata\nH 22 * * * % RELEASE=scapa''')])
])
```

Comment: What's the error message? I copied this on top of a sample "Hello World" pipeline and it worked as expected.

Comment: I get the below error while running in a scripted pipeline.

Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] properties
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
line 1:1: unexpected char: 'T'
 at 
Caused: antlr.ANTLRException: Invalid input: "TZ=Asia/Kolkata

Comment: What's the version of your `parameterized-scheduler` plugin? They added support for timezones about two years ago in version 1.0